# Failing to Install ROS apt packages on clean Ubuntu

Tags: ros, ubuntu-20.04, apt

On a machine running a just installed Ubuntu 20.04.5 OS,
I'm trying to install some packages, specifically the [ROS framework](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu).

The process fails in step 1.4 of such (taken from the ROS install guide):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cWcK.png)

after running the `sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full` I get the following output:

```
ros-noetic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-noetic-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-noetic-perception but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-noetic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-noetic-urdf-sim-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I should say that the first time I did this, I set the package server for software download to 'main server' instead of the regional server automatically assigned and set the update request to 'Never', and got the message

```
error while refreshing cache ubuntu pk-client-error-quark
```

I have tried fixing the broken dependencies with the apt commands, I've google the problem and the terminal output but haven't been able to solve the problem.

I ran into this problem in two different machines, and when tried to replicate in a VM with 'Boxes' inside my dev-machine I didn't face the same issue.

I should also add that I am not a Linux expert by any means, and that I might have done or do something that's beyond me yet. However, any suggestions/explanations are highly welcomed.

best regards

Comment: Hi, Have you tried running sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full --fix-broken command?

Comment: `sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full --fix-broken` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it looks unrelated, but in my case, the problem was Ubuntu update settings.In `Software Updater`, go to settings and make sure you are subscribed to all updates (not only security updates).[image]